# Firestore - saving external links in a document with both url and title

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

How can I create an array in firestore that can save external links?

I want to save the title and the href so that I can use both values in the read.

I want the links attribute to be an array so that I can save multiple links. Is it possible to do that in a single firebase attribute, or should I create separate link attributes with a href and title for each one (ie firstLinkTitle, firstLinkHref)?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to have a number of links, that would be a different array - similar to an array of arrays.

The possibility for the creation of a field of type `array` for your documents, you can either use the console, where this type is available or via code as the following example:

```
const data = {
  stringExample: 'Example',
  arrayExample: ['Title', 'href']
};

const res = await db.collection('data').doc('one').set(data);
```

With the above example, you should be able to create a field of type array and set the data to it.
Besides that, if you want to update data from your array without uploading all the data again, you can use the function `arrayUnion()` or use the `arrayRemove()`, to remove elements from it.

You can get more information on how to work with arrays in Firestore, by checking the below documentation.

- [Add Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)

In case you need something like nested arrays, indeed, you will need to have a "child" collection that will be linked to the father one.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Hi, no. I want an array = links as [ doc name, doc url ], [doc name, doc url]. Your suggestion doesn't work because each link has a different title. The array attribute in firebase doesn't allow another array.

Comment: Hi @Mel I have updated my answer, providing example for array type now.

Comment: I musnt be asking clearly, my array is a number of links, with each link comprising of 2 attributes. It does not appear to be possible to create this structure from the firebase console. So far as I can see, I can make a table for each link as a child of the main attribute or do it like I set out in the question. Thanks anyway for trying to help.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Yes, you are correct, you will need a separate table for the goal you are trying to achieve. I have updated my answer with this information as well. If you think it helped you or that might help the community, consider upvoting or accepting it. :)

Comment: Thanks - but still not what I'm asking. I think I must be communicating without clarity for you. Thanks anyway for trying to help.